# How to restrict a sitecore droptree field to accept only media folder item and not allow media items

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

I'm trying to use a droptree field to allow content editors to pick one folder item from a tree of items. Here i have to restrict the droptree field to accept only media folder item and it should not allow media items like image and videos. I have set the source as datasource:

```
DataSource=/sitecore/media library/User Submitted Media&ExcludeTemplatesForSelection=Jpeg,Image
```

The above mentioned datasource is not working. Still i am able to select both media item and media folder. Sitecore version i am using is 7.2. Am i missing anything?

Comment: Try 'ExcludeTemplatesForDisplay' instead of 'ExcludeTemplatesForSelection'.

Comment: @AlekseyShevchenko I have tried ExcludeTemplatesForDisplay but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Include/Exclude TemplatesForDisplay/Selection with DropTree. See this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35739954/3553746)